# Simple ring/circular buffer C++ class

Tags: c++, circular-list

I've got this simple ring/circular buffer class:

```
template<class T, size_t sz>
class CircularBuffer {

    std::array<T, sz> buffer;
    size_t head;
    size_t tail;
    bool isFull;

public:
    CircularBuffer() :
        head{0},
        tail{0},
        isFull{false} {
    }

    void put(T item) {
        buffer[head] = item;
        head = (head + 1) % sz;
        if (isFull) {
            tail = (tail + 1) % sz;
        }
        isFull = head == tail;
    }

    T get() {
        auto result = buffer[tail];
        tail = (tail + 1) % sz;
        isFull = false;
        return result;
    }

    bool empty() const {
        return tail == head;
    }

    size_t capacity() const {
        return sz;
    }

    size_t size() const {
        if (isFull)
            return sz;

        if (head >= tail)
            return head - tail;

        return sz + head - tail;
    }
};
```

And I was looking for clarification on a few things, to take advantage of C++ features.

First, the new `constexpr` keyword, what here, if anything should I apply it to? (I'm assuming the `size_t size() const` member function could use it? Anything else?)

Second, all of these member functions are quite small, should they be `inlined`?

Third, in the `T get()` member function, I do `auto result = buffer[tail];`, should I use `auto&` instead, or any other versions? (or even just `T`/`T&`?) Should that be a const as it's not modified within the function, and only potentially modified once a copy is returned via the functions return parameter.

Any other feedback is welcome!

Comment: Relevant: [*Titling your question*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help Center.

Comment: @yuri I don't really care about this specific classes implementation, rather I'm trying to understand why/when to use keywords etc. The class itself is irrelevant and instead just being used as an example.

Comment: @AlexV What would you title it if the question isn't about the class code, and instead about the c++ features I'm asking about? Because I could put any class code in the example, the questions would remain the same.

Comment: "General purpose questions" are IMHO not suited for Code Review. As the Help Center puts it: "In order to give good advice, we need to see real, concrete code, and understand the context in which the code is used. Generic code  [...] leaves too much to the imagination." ([source](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: Since you are asking to take advantage of language features, please specify what version of C++ you are targeting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Interface

### Naming

Functions returning a `bool` should be phrased as a question. `empty` should be `is_empty` instead. Yes, the standard library does it wrong too, leading to confusion like "I used `vector.empty();`, but it didn't empty my vector. Why?"
`get` should be `pop` or `pop_get`. Getters are not supposed to change the object.
Note that it is impossible to write `get` with the [strong exception guarantee](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions), which is the reason why `std::vector::pop_back` returns `void` instead of the element.

### `constexpr`

Currently you can mark all your functions `constexpr`. Sometimes it is possible to evaluate the result of your `CircularBuffer` at compile time. That probably rarely comes up, but there is no good reason not to do it (yet).

### Generality

#### Type restrictions

There are limits for what `T`s I can use your `CircularBuffer` with. `T` must be copyable and default constructible. That means I cannot use a `struct Foo{ Foo(int); };` or a `std::unique_ptr<int>`. Arguably those should be allowed.

Move-Only

Supporting move-only types is possible by using `std::move` in the appropriate spots, mainly `buffer[head] = std::move(item);` and `auto result = std::move(buffer[tail]);`. Just try to use a `CircularBuffer<std::unique_ptr<int>>` and the compiler will tell you about each spot.

Non-Default-Constructible

To be able to use `CircularBuffer<Foo>` you would need to delay constructing objects until the user uses `put`. You can achieve that by changing `std::array<T, sz> buffer;` to `alignas(alignof(T)) std::array<char, sz * sizeof(T)> buffer;`. That way no `T`s are default constructed. When you add an element in `put` you have to placement `new` the element: `new (&buffer[head * sizeof(T)]) T(std::move(item));`. `get` then has to call `std::destroy_at(reinterpret_cast<T*>(&buffer[tail * sizeof(T)]));` (or just call the destructor). This makes things more complicated and also `reinterpret_cast` and `new` are not `constexpr`.

Brick Types

Some types like `std::mutex` cannot be copied or moved, but you could still support them. To do that, offer an `emplace` function similar to `std::vector::emplace_back` that constructs the  `T` in place from a given list of arguments.

### `get` Return Type

Returning a `T` by value seems reasonable. You are taking out the element. Returning a `T &` instead seems dangerous, because usage of the buffer will eventually change the value you got. Maybe add 2 `peek` functions instead that return a reference to the current object without removing it. One of the functions would be `T &peek()` and the other `const T &peek() const`.

## Bugs

### `empty` When Full

```
CircularBuffer<int, 3> b;
b.put(1);
b.put(2);
b.put(3);
std::cout << std::boolalpha << b.empty();
```

That should really not print `true`.

### Over- and Underflow

If I `put` more items into the buffer than it has space it silently overwrites objects. If I try to `get` items without putting items in, it simply returns uninitialized objects which is undefined behavior for builtins. This is my fault for using your container incorrectly, but you could be nice and add an `assert` so that I can find my bug easier.

### `inline`

Your functions are already implicitly marked `inline` which changes the linkage and has nothing to do with inlining. Whether inlining is the right choice is a complicated case-by-case question that you should leave to your compiler. Only use [`inline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/inline) to mean "I want internal linkage", which you can also do for variables since C++17.

Comment: It is highly questionable to suggest naming conventions that arecontradictory to standard practices demonstrated by the standard (e.g `empty` vs `is_empty`)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to go in depth on everything, I guess I should clarify why I hadn't put anything in place to support different types of T, currently the code was only being used by another data-structure that only uses unsigned ints with it, as far as the get and put, those are also both only called by the data structure so i hadn't really bothered to make it very client facing friendly. That said, thanks for catching the empty bug. Out of curiosity, would adding all the extra stuff to support all the other types, add much overhead? I'm trying to keep this as fast as possible.

Comment: also what do you mean with "When you add an element in put you have to placement new the element: `new &buffer[head * sizeof(T)] T(std::move(item));`." I'm not sure how that code is supposed to work?

Comment: When you use `new` it normally allocates dynamic memory, constructs an object of given type with given arguments there and returns a pointer to that object. But you can optionally provide memory instead. (I messed up the syntax and forgot the parenthesis around the address). That way it constructs an object in the given memory without needing dynamic memory allocation. It's only needed if you have need a memory buffer that sometimes contains objects and sometimes doesn't, which is the case here if you decide to support creating and destroying objects as needed.

Comment: As for the performance of [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new), the constructor and destructor for `unsigned int` don't do anything at runtime, so there should be no difference. Technically you are not allowed to access objects that don't exist, so you can't just cast the address of `buffer` to a `T *` and access the `T` that isn't there. That also applies to `unsigned int`s.

Comment: @miscco "standard practice" is to use question phrasing (`is_empty`). Just because part of the C++ standard library does something is no reason to recommend doing the same (c.f. the naming in the iostreams part of the library).

Comment: @user673679 I believe that this is a problem with programmers blaming others for their own mistakes. There is no qualitative difference between `empty` and `size` both describe the state of the object in question. If you go down the "boolean return value should be a verb" then you would also need to go for `getSize` and `getCapacity`. Btw the phrasing `empty` for removing elements from the container would be semantically much worse than `clear`

Comment: @miscco There is a difference. `empty` is ambiguous. It could ask if the container is empty or empty it. `size` is not ambiguous. It tells you the size. The command would be `resize` or at least require a parameter.

Comment: @miscco Yeah, I'd say `getSize()` and `getCapacity()` are also better names. Using a verb can help to distinguish other things too, e.g. returning something that's instantly accessible (`getFoo()`) and performing an operation that might have a significant performance impact (`calculateFoo()`).

Comment: @nwp So I've been adding the functionality you mentioned above, and one thing i'm unsure of, what's the proper order for the cleanup in the "get" function, would it be something along the lines of `auto location = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&buffer[tail * sizeof(T)]); auto result = std::move(*location); std::destroy_at(location);`? The I know that the destroy would only be called on the copy that is at the memory location in the buffer, but would the use of "move" here cause problems? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HexCrown Seems reasonable. First you move the object out and then you destroy the old object. What C++ calls "moving" is just a copy that steals resources from the original. But the original still exists in a valid state, so you can destruct it without problems.