# Simple ring/circular buffer c++ class V2

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, circular-list

[The Original Post (v1)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/219888/simple-ring-circular-buffer-c-class)

I'm looking for feedback on the updated version of the code posted at the link above.

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>

namespace datastructures {

    template<class _Ty, size_t _Size>
    class CircularBufferv2 {

        // uses char as type to prevent default _Ty initialization.
        alignas(alignof(_Ty)) char buffer[_Size * sizeof(_Ty)];
        size_t head;
        size_t tail;
        bool isFull;

    public:
        constexpr CircularBufferv2() noexcept :
            buffer{0},
            head{0},
            tail{0},
            isFull{false} {
        }

        void push(const _Ty& item) noexcept {
            assert(!isFull && "Attempting to push item into full buffer!");

            new (&buffer[head * sizeof(_Ty)]) _Ty(std::move(item));

            head = ++head % _Size;
            isFull = head == tail;
        }

        _Ty pop() noexcept {
            assert(!is_empty() && "Attempting to pop item from empty buffer!");

            auto location = reinterpret_cast<_Ty*>(&buffer[tail * sizeof(_Ty)]);
            auto result = std::move(*location);
            std::destroy_at(location);

            tail = ++tail % _Size;
            isFull = false;

            return result;
        }

        _NODISCARD constexpr _Ty& peek() noexcept {
            assert(!is_empty() && "Attempting to peek in empty buffer!");

            return *reinterpret_cast<_Ty*>(&buffer[tail * sizeof(_Ty)]);
        }

        _NODISCARD constexpr const _Ty& peek() const noexcept {
            assert(!is_empty() && "Attempting to peek in empty buffer!");

            return *reinterpret_cast<_Ty*>(&buffer[tail * sizeof(_Ty)]);
        }

        _NODISCARD constexpr bool is_empty() const noexcept {
            return !isFull && tail == head;
        }

        _NODISCARD constexpr size_t get_capacity() const noexcept {
            return _Size;
        }

        _NODISCARD constexpr size_t get_size() const noexcept {
            if (isFull)
                return _Size;

            if (head >= tail)
                return head - tail;

            return _Size + head - tail;
        }

        _NODISCARD _CONSTEXPR17 _Ty* data() noexcept {
            return buffer;
        }

        _NODISCARD _CONSTEXPR17 const _Ty* data() const noexcept {
            return buffer;
        }
    };
}
```

I want to take advantage of all of the new features(c++17) while also supporting older compilers(preferably all older compilers but c++11 is probably as old as i'll actually be compiling for). Any suggestions welcome. (I'm attempting to use this class as an example class to follow when constructing other classes.)

Also, the use of `_CONSTEXPR17` on the `data` functions I was wondering why use the macro vs just a `constexpr`? (I based the use of macros around the `std::array` struct, its data function uses `_CONSTEXPR17` rather than just `constexpr`.)

Comment: You are aiming for C++11/C++17 compilers, yet use non-standard macros. Why? Why not stick to the standard?

Comment: Identifiers starting with underscore followed by a capitol letter are reserved for the implementation. i.e. They are not designed for use by application developers and thus you should not be using them. In this context `_Ty`, `_Size`, `_CONTEXPR17`, `_NODISCARD` should not be used in your code.

Comment: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/14065)

Comment: You probably shouldn’t be using `v2` in the class name anyway. Consider using inline namespaces if you need different versions.

Comment: @L.F. v2 will be removed once i finalize the class so you can ignore that.

Comment: @MartinYork So the macros for contexpr etc shouldnt be used? Also I didn't realize those macros were non standard, I saw them used in the std::array implementation so I assumed they were standard, is there something that should be used instead?

Comment: @HexCrown Those identifiers are "reserved for the implementation" this means the compiler and the library shipped with the compiler is allowed to use them (so using them with `std::array` is OK). But they are not designed to be used by application developers. Be careful of using the term `Non Standard` that is not a correct usage of that term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a char array you can use `std::aligned_storage`.

You aren't consistent with your macros you have both `constexpr` and `_CONSTEXPR17`. Pick one and stick to it.

`destroy_at` is standard only from C++17 onward. The equivalent syntax is `location->~_Ty();` However it may be worth to put this and the placement new into a helper function to move the ugly syntax elsewhere and clarify the function.

You don't have a move variant of push or a bulk add/remove using iterators.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason for your users to access your internal buffer? To me that data methods shouldn't be there.

Don't like very much those reinterpret_cast but I see you have those there to support not default constructable types. I could live with those and get back that additional feature as long as that implementation detail is sealed into the class.

Comment: What do you mean by "I could live with those and get back that additional feature as long as that implementation detail is sealed into the class."?

Comment: Right now you are giving access to external users to your implementation details. Your users need to know how to get Ty from the internal buffer. That is not a nice thing if the access is not that straight forward.