# Simple ring/circular buffer c++ class V3

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, circular-list

[The Original Post (v2)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220690/simple-ring-circular-buffer-c-class-v2)

As stated in the previous post, i'm looking for feedback on the updated version of the code posted.

A few things specifically I'm looking for feedback on, are:

- I switched to using the `std::aligned_storage` as suggested in the previous post, but on the [cppreference.com - std::aligned_storage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) page, in the examples it says `// note: needs std::launder as of C++17` above the `reinterpret_cast`'s. Would that mean, that the launder function should just wrap the cast, and if so, it states that its needed for c++17, which is what I'm using, but I'd also like the code to be compatible back to c++11. What would be the recommended approach in this situation?
- I was considering making a private function, something like:

  ```
  #include <new>
  // ...
  [[nodiscard]] const T* ptr_to(std::size_t pos) const {
      return std::launder(reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&data[pos]));
  }
  ```

  to remove some of the code duplication, I'm still trying to gain a better understanding of `const` correctness, would I need a const version and a non-const version of this function, similar to the `peek` function?
- Like I mentioned in a previous point, I'm wanting to target c++17 primarily, but also be backward compatible down to c++11. Language features such as `[[nodiscard]]` and `std::launder` are c++17 only, is there a standard way(using macros or otherwise) to accommodate for this?
- The function `void push(const T& item) noexcept` takes a const ref and uses `std::move` internally on it, is that reasonable? or should that only be done to params such as `T&& item`? Should I just delete the `std::move` in that function?
- Any suggestions for cutting down on code duplication are welcome.

CircularBuffer.h

```
#pragma once

#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>

namespace datastructures {

    template<class T, std::size_t N>
    class CircularBuffer {

        typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type data[N];
        std::size_t head = 0;
        std::size_t tail = 0;
        bool isFull = false;


    public:
        template<typename ...Args>
        void emplace_push(Args&&... args) noexcept {
            assert(!isFull && "Attempting to push item into full buffer!");

            new (&data[head]) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

            head = ++head % N;
            isFull = head == tail;
        }

        void push(const T& item) noexcept {
            assert(!isFull && "Attempting to push item into full buffer!");

            new (&data[head]) T(std::move(item));

            head = ++head % N;
            isFull = head == tail;
        }

        T pop() noexcept {
            assert(!is_empty() && "Attempting to pop item from empty buffer!");

            auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[tail]);
            auto result = std::move(*ptr);
            ptr->~T();

            tail = ++tail % N;
            isFull = false;

            return result;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr T& peek() noexcept {
            assert(!is_empty() && "Attempting to peek in empty buffer!");

            return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[tail]);
        }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr const T& peek() const noexcept {
            assert(!is_empty() && "Attempting to peek in empty buffer!");

            return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&data[tail]);
        }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr bool is_empty() const noexcept {
            return !isFull && tail == head;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr std::size_t get_capacity() const noexcept {
            return N;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] constexpr std::size_t get_size() const noexcept {
            if (isFull)
                return N;

            if (head >= tail)
                return head - tail;

            return N + head - tail;
        }
    };
}
```

---

Edit: I started using the macro:

```
#ifdef __has_cpp_attribute
#  if __has_cpp_attribute(nodiscard)
#    define NO_DISCARD [[nodiscard]]
#  else
#    define NO_DISCARD
#  endif
#else
#  define NO_DISCARD
#endif
```

for the `[[nodiscard]]` on the functions. Is this reasonably portable / acceptable or is there anything better, also still looking for a good way to conditionally add the `std::launder` part if available in the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you want to

> target [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) primarily, but also be backward compatible down to [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

Consider changing this to

> target [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) primarily, but also be compatible with [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)

Because you can't really use most of the [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) stuff here.
You have to write code in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11),
but also take care of [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) compatibility.
To be honest, I don't think this is a good idea,
but I will respect your opinion anyway.

I don't know much about `std::launder`,
but I remember someone saying that the code with theoretical undefined behavior
will do the right job on any (sane) implementation.
I'm not gonna care much about it here.

## Bugs

1. Your code does not implement RAII and is not exception-safe.
   You should add a destructor to clean up the contents.
   You should also implement (copy|move) (constructors|assignments).
   The [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543) can help you.

   Note that the automatically generated destructor
   does not call the destructor of `T`,
   and the automatically generated copy and move stuff
   do not call the copy and move stuff of `T`.
   They just copy the raw `char`s,
   which is clearly not intended.

   Here's an example of what a destructor might look like:

   ```
   ~CircularBuffer()
   {
       if (is_empty())
           return;

       std::size_t i = tail;
       do {
           reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[i])->~T();
           i = (i + 1) % N;
       } while (i != head);
   }
   ```

   And the copy constructor and move constructor:

   ```
   CircularBuffer(const CircularBuffer& other)
       :head{other.head}, tail{other.tail}, isFull{other.isFull}
   {
       // note: not exception safe
       if (!is_empty()) {
           for (; i != head; i = (i + 1) % N)
               new (&data[i]) T(other.data[i]);
     }
   }

   CircularBuffer(CircularBuffer&& other)
       :head{other.head}, tail{other.tail}, isFull{other.isFull}
   {
       // note: not exception safe
       if (!is_empty())
           for (std::size_t i = tail; i < head; i = (i + 1) % N)
               new (&data[i]) T(std::move(other.data[i]));
   }
   ```

## Suggestions

1. The following code is confusing:

   ```
   head = ++head % N;
   ```

   Granted, it works as intended since [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11),
   but still, consider changing to the more readable

   ```
   head = (head + 1) % N;
   ```

   This will prevent any confusion.
2. `push` accepts a `const T&` and `std::move`s from it.
   This makes no sense.
   `std::move(item)` will return a `const T&&`
   and usually binds to `const T&` copy constructors.
   Pass-by-value instead:

   ```
   void push(T item) noexcept { /* ... */ }
   ```

   This will handle both copying and moving correctly.
3. Moreover, `push` should probably delegate to `emplace_push`
   to reduce code duplication.

   ```
   void push(T item) noexcept
   {
       emplace_push(std::move(item));
   }
   ```
4. `pop` should not return the popped value
   because it cannot do this in a safe way.<sup>1</sup>
   Instead, let `pop` return `void`
   and let `peek` do its job.

By the way, there is much debate on `#pragma once` (see, for example, [`#pragma once` vs include guards?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1143936)). I think it is OK here, but others may disagree.

---

<sup>1</sup> The move constructor of `T` may throw an exception,
in which case the popped object is leaked and cannot be restored.

Comment: So I've made almost all the changes mentioned aside from the constructor related ones, firstly, are copy/move/etc constructors not automatically generated if no constructor is defined? I thought they were? Aside from that, how are template parameters handled when dealing with copy constructors etc, would you be able to give a very basic example with at least the aligned storage member variable? Thanks.

Comment: @Hex I have updated my answer to answer your first question. For the example, wait a moment

Comment: I also added a "move push" `  void push(T&& item) noexcept {
   assert(!isFull && "error: buffer is full!");
   new (&data[head]) T(std::move(item));
   increment_head();
  }` is it proper to use the std::move here or is that redundant as the `item` is already type `T&&` ?

Comment: @Hex You have to still use `move` because `item` is an lvalue although it is of type `T&&`. That said, you can unify the copy push and move push a pass-by-value push (see point 2 and 3).

Comment: So am I understanding correctly that by having the 2 shown already (emplace and by value) I don't need a move option? or am I understanding incorrectly?

Comment: @Hex Yes, exactly. The pass-by-value `push` shown in point 2 and 3 handles both copy and move properly.

Comment: @Hex I have updated my answer to include an example of what a destructor may look like.