# Simple ring/circular buffer c++ class V4

Tags: c++, c++17, circular-list

As the title states, this is my 4th revision of this class.
[Here is the previous post if needed.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220775/simple-ring-circular-buffer-c-class-v3)

I'm hoping someone experienced with things such as `noexcept`, `[[nodiscard]]`, etc can go over the uses in the class below any make sure I'm on the right track?

Further more, I've attempted to implement the [copy and swap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279550/4831051) and would like to know if my implementation looks accurate?

I've changed `data` private member variable to `std::array` from the previous "c-style" array, was that a reasonable thing to do?

I've noticed that `std::aligned_storage` is in `<type_traits>` which also appears to supply an `std::move` and `std::forward` but [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) mentions forward is in `<utility>`, that site also shows `std::move` in `<utility>` or `<algorithm>` how do I know if I'm including the correct files?

I'm also looking for any feedback on overlooked bugs/problems with my implementation, as well as any other feature suggestions. (I'm attempting to use this class as a standard for my future work so I'm trying to pack as much knowledge into it as possible.)

```
#pragma once // not looking for feedback on include guard.

#include <new> // std::launder
#include <array> // std::array
#include <cstddef> // std::size_t
#include <cassert> // assert
#include <type_traits> // std::aligned_storage_t, std::forward, std::move

#include "../LangMacros.h" // NO_DISCARD

namespace datastructures {

    template<class T, std::size_t N>
    class RingBuffer {

        std::array<std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>, N> data;
        std::size_t head;
        std::size_t tail;
        bool isFull;

        NO_DISCARD T* ptr_to(std::size_t pos) noexcept {
            return std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[pos]));
        }

        NO_DISCARD const T* ptr_to(std::size_t pos) const noexcept {
            return std::launder(reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&data[pos]));
        }

    public:
        // default
        constexpr RingBuffer() noexcept :
            data{},
            head{0},
            tail{0},
            isFull{false} {
        };

        // copy
        RingBuffer(const RingBuffer& other) :
            data{},
            head{other.head},
            tail{other.tail},
            isFull{other.isFull}
        {
            // can this function be noexcept?
            if (!is_empty())
                // ignore bug with this for loop iteration
                for (std::size_t i = tail; i < head; i = (i + 1) % N)
                    new (&data[i]) T(*other.ptr_to(i)); // `other.data[i]` give cosnt _Ty which causes error, why?
        }

        // move
        /* replaced with "swap-move" below instead
        RingBuffer(RingBuffer&& other) :
            data{},
            head{other.head},
            tail{other.tail},
            isFull{other.isFull}
        {
            // note: not exception safe
            if (!is_empty())
                for (std::size_t i = tail; i < head; i = (i + 1) % N)
                    new (&data[i]) T(std::move(other.data[i]));
        }
        */

        // swap-move
        RingBuffer(RingBuffer&& other) :
            RingBuffer() // initialize via default constructor, C++11 only
        {
            swap(*this, other);
        }

        ~RingBuffer() noexcept {
            clear();
        }

        // using https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279550/4831051 as a reference, can this be constexpr / noexcept?
        friend void swap(RingBuffer& first, RingBuffer& second) /*nothrow*/ {
            using std::swap;

            swap(first.data, second.data); //TODO is this safe?!
            swap(first.head, second.head);
            swap(first.tail, second.tail);
            swap(first.isFull, second.isFull);
        }

        RingBuffer& operator=(RingBuffer other) {
            swap(*this, other);

            return *this;
        }

        void clear() noexcept {
            while (!is_empty()) pop();
        }

        template<typename ...Args>
        void emplace_push(Args&&... args) noexcept {
            assert(!isFull && "error: buffer is full!");

            new (&data[head]) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

            head = (head + 1) % N;
            isFull = head == tail;
        }

        void push(T item) noexcept {
            emplace_push(std::move(item));
        }

        void pop() noexcept {
            assert(!is_empty() && "error: buffer is empty!");

            ptr_to(tail)->~T();

            tail = (tail + 1) % N;
            isFull = false;
        }

        NO_DISCARD constexpr T& peek() noexcept {
            assert(!is_empty() && "error: buffer is empty!");

            return *ptr_to(tail);
        }

        NO_DISCARD constexpr const T& peek() const noexcept {
            assert(!is_empty() && "error: buffer is empty!");

            return *ptr_to(tail);
        }

        NO_DISCARD constexpr bool is_empty() const noexcept {
            return !isFull && tail == head;
        }

        NO_DISCARD constexpr std::size_t get_capacity() const noexcept {
            return N;
        }

        NO_DISCARD constexpr std::size_t get_size() const noexcept {
            if (isFull)
                return N;

            if (head >= tail)
                return head - tail;

            return N + head - tail;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: There are two distinct function templates called `move`. The one you are looking for is declared in `<utility>`.

Comment: That's where you'll find `std::forward()` too.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>        swap(first.data, second.data); //TODO is this safe?!
> ```

It is not generally safe, because either of those `data` members may be holding objects, and those objects need to be *moved* (or *swapped*, for parts of the array where both containers hold objects).  It's safe only for plain-old-data types, certainly not so if `T` has non-trivial constructor or destructor.

---

The interface makes it hard to use `emplace_push()` safely.  Consider providing a public `is_full()` predicate so that users can tell whether there's room for another element yet.

---

An important use-case for a ring buffer is to pass data from one thread to another.  But this class has no locking, preventing it from being used it that way.  Consider making it thread-safe - or perhaps not: users will need locking to cover `is_full(); emplace_push()` unless the latter is modified to return an indication of failure.